Flutter Material Dynamic Colors missing surfaces and elevation colors
I'm starting with Flutter and Material You dynamic colors. After setting up the example app, I tried using the dynamic color from my device. But instead of correctly rendering background and elevated elements, it makes all my surfaces the same color. SurfaceContainer, SurfaceContainerLow, SurfaceContainerHighest... all have the same white color. Elevated buttons blend with the background. Using a color scheme from a seed works perfectly.
I even tried opening demo projects with a lot of colors, Even with these I can't make dynamic colors work properly. Any ideas?
Here is my code that does not work.
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dynamic_color/dynamic_color.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: DynamicColorBuilder(
        builder: (ColorScheme? lightDynamic, ColorScheme? darkDynamic) {
          ColorScheme lightColorScheme;
          ColorScheme darkColorScheme;

          if (lightDynamic != null && darkDynamic != null) {
            lightColorScheme = lightDynamic;
            darkColorScheme = darkDynamic;
          } else {
            lightColorScheme = ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepOrange);
            darkColorScheme = ColorScheme.fromSeed(
                seedColor: Colors.deepOrange, brightness: Brightness.dark);
          }

          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Namer App',
            theme: ThemeData(
              useMaterial3: true,
              colorScheme: lightColorScheme,
            ),
            darkTheme: ThemeData(
              useMaterial3: true,
              colorScheme: darkColorScheme,
            ),
            home: MyHomePage(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var current = WordPair.random();

  void getNext() {
    current = WordPair.random();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('\n\n\nA random AWESOME idea:'),
          Text(appState.current.asLowerCase),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              appState.getNext();
            },
            child: Text('Next'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

By changing these lines, I can see what the color theme should look like (here I am just generating a palette from the primary of the dynamic colors):
if (lightDynamic != null && darkDynamic != null) {
            lightColorScheme = ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: lightDynamic.primary);
            darkColorScheme = ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: darkDynamic.primary, brightness: Brightness.dark);

You can see side by side the difference, notice how the button on the first one blends with the background.
with dynamic colors
without dynamic colors
similar example, with and without adaptive colors. notice the navigation bar blending with adaptive colors.
Thank you for your help.

Downgrade to Dart SDK 3.3.4 and Flutter SDK 3.19.6

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

THANK YOU! after trying to inserts parts of my code in public projects and see them not working as well i was ready to give up and accept that the library was flawed. so glad to learn a previous version fixes it!
by the way, may i ask how you knew about this fix?

I had a project I made a while ago that used dynamic colors and it worked fine. A few weeks ago, I upgraded to the latest Dart and Flutter version and the dynamic colors were broken. When I tried downgrading to the latest 3.19.x version, everything worked fine.

There is a open issue on GitHub to fix that, but no updates until now. Hope they fix it soon.
